# XMPP authentication returns yes but XMPPStreamDidAuthenticate never called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, xmpp

I am trying to create an application that implements Facebook Chat.  I have set up all of the XMPP stuff correctly to the best of my knowledge, but I cannot get it to work.

After the user has logged in and been authenticated to Facebook (via `FBSession`) I try to connect to the chat service.  Here is where the XMPP comes in:

```
-(void)connect
{
    [self setupStream];
    NSError *err;

    [self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:10.00 error:&err];
}

-(void)setupStream
{
    _xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] initWithFacebookAppId:FACEBOOK_APP_ID];
    [self.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    NSError *error;
    NSError *err;
    [self.xmppStream secureConnection:&err];
    bool authed = [self.xmppStream authenticateWithFacebookAccessToken: FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", err);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.xmppStream authenticationDate]);
    NSLog(@"%d, %@", authed, error);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    NSLog(@"did authenticate");
    [self goOnline];
}
```

When running the above, everything seems to go fine: `xmppStreamDidConnect` is called after a short wait and `authed` always returns YES and its error is always `null`.

However, `secureConnection` returns **Error Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=1 "Please wait until the stream is connected." UserInfo=0xb23dc30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Please wait until the stream is connected.}**  The `authenticationDate` is always `null` as well.  Also, none of the other delegate methods are ever called, including `xmppStreamDidAuthenticate`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found my answer!! Here it is, in case anyone else runs in to the same problem as me:

When calling `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:` the `FBSession` object does not actually communicate with the Facebook servers or attempt to authenticate with them, it simply loads the previous authenticationToken.  In my case, this token had become invalid, but I did not realize it and nothing was there to tell me.  I finally figured it out by logging the token and putting it in Facebook's [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token?q=CAAIrv4ysBeQBAB7Wj9a3goYxfYljr75O2sqFdVcoNtVsElU8hEE6pOe7BW0oEnfZAKAyX3SlrmU5Ps9Nwo5TpsJ3m3ZCPvBZCNCHX5fao4GHtT2KTuP8xhpEXsbUS4Y0ZBn65QONFZAy8wvseraPXxsB5JZBjkacgoZCAsyKfCCSgcZCWJ9UUC0CAKwbCXLv473L441JJlNJU0APfju4OCNN).  To check if your token is valid, you must call `[FBSession renewSystemCredentials:]` and await the result.  Then you can determine if you need to manually `closeAndClearTokenInformation` before attempting to create a new token.

Comment: What has this answer to do with the actual question?